# What to use instead of window.getLocation() in a textarea in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple `textarea` where I want the user to be able to select/highlight text to make it bold, italicized, etc., much like the one I'm writing in now.

I actually get it working using a `onKeyDown` method and then using `window.getSelection()`, but I feel it's the wrong approach to use `window` in React. Correct? If so, what do I use instead?

```
handleKeyDown(event) {
    const highlightedText = window.getSelection().toString()
    console.log(highlightedText)
},

render() {
    return (
        <textarea onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} />
    )
}
```

Comment: It's really on special keypresses, but I felt that wasn't pertinent to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to use `window.getSelection` in React. The only issue I see here in terms of breaking the component model and getting unexpected results, is the case where you call the method inside your component, but the selection is actually on a different element on the page.

In your case since you are calling `getSelection` inside the `onKeyDown` handler, you know the selection must have come from this component instance, since it needs to be focused to receive the event.

But if you would like to be able to get the selection at any time inside a component in a safe way, you could create a member function on the component to check if it's focused using [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```
getSelection() {
    return (this.refs.container === document.activeElement) ?
        window.getSelection() : null;
}

render() {
    return (
        <textarea onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} ref="container" />
    )
}
```

Here `getSelection()` will return the selection if it's within this component instance, otherwise null.

Answer (score 2):

The time when things can go wrong is when you modify the DOM outside of React. But this is not the case.

I don't mind calling `window.getSelection` in my react code. I've been using `document` methods/attrs like `document.activeElement` and `window` methods/attr like `window.innerHeight` and `setTimeout`. I have come across no problem and I did not find any other better way to get what I want.

This does need some attention in test though. You need to set up the window object and make it available to your test code.